# Text2wave festival not working via nginx php exec

Tags: php, nginx, festival

I'm trying to run a shell command text2wave in PHP on a nginx server.

The problem is the command just exits silently without working as it should. It's also not displaying any errors.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$result = `/usr/bin/text2wave --help`;
var_dump($result);
```

If I run the script via php command in shell ( as a normal user) it works as expected.
However, If I run it via a http request through nginx the var_dump returns NULL
( there are also not logs in error log files)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe because the php instance doesn't have permission to run the command, check the permissions and ownership of the executable `text2wave`

Comment: the permissions are -rwxr-xr-x. Same as the program festival which workes perfectly via nginx php

Comment: try to enable `ini_set('display_errors','on')` in the first line and see if it shows any thing.

Comment: nope... no php errors

Comment: try using `/usr/bin/text2wave --help 2>&1` and see if it shows any output.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
<?php
function sys_cmd($cmd)
{   
    $hd = popen($cmd,"r") or die('function disabled');
    while (!feof($hd))
    {
        $rs .= fread($hd,1024);     
    }
    pclose($hd);
    return $rs;
}
echo sys_cmd('ls -l');
?>
```

Comment: the script works with 'ls -l', but not with 'text2wave --help' ( nor normal usage of text2wave of course)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you've got shell execution disabled in the `php.ini` configuration file used by your web server.

Try opening `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file, finding the `disable_functions` directive, and making sure that **none** of the following functions are present in the value of the directive: `shell_exec,exec,passthru,system`

Comment: Can you explain how that magically executes OP's `$result = '/usr/bin/text2wave --help';`? Look at it again — that's a (string) variable assignment, not a function. OP doesn't have to fix any configuration; instead, OP needs to correct his PHP code.

Comment: Oh, those are *"backticks"*! I thought those were formatting errors… (hits head against the wall) My bad; you're absolutely correct. Thanks for the heads-up. I've removed my incorrect answer accordingly. From my point of view, you'll get that bounty well deserved! On the other hand, looking at the fact that I didn't notice the difference between single-quotes and backticks, my *"view"* might not be the best to rely on. ;)

Comment: shell exec works. it doesn't work through nginx php running text2wave

Answer (score 0):

To anybody haing the same problem... I've managed to find out what the problem was. Well.. kind of.

I've switched to apache and it started working right away. So the solution is not to use nginx

I guess it had something to do with the way nginx ran php when doing exec commands...

Although it was a hard decision, I found no other solution but to change to apache... works well now